# How to dial into existing Twilio conference using GSM phone number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have an ongoing Twilio conference with two participants. As a third party, I want to join that conference by calling Twilio phone number and entering extension code using dialpad. What TwiML should I return from my WebHook handler to join that call into an existing conference?

There is a TwiML `Dial Conference` verb, but seems like it only works with conference name, not SID. I want to join with conference SID.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>CFXXXX...</Conference> <!-- Doesn't work! -->
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to connect to the conference by ConferenceSid is first to get Conference by sid:

```
TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var conference = ConferenceResource.Fetch(
    pathSid: "CFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
);
```

then you will be available to get Conference FriendlyName property and connect by providing it in Twiml.